# select the rows that have more that X occurrences of the same foreign key and ignore the X most recent (timestamp)

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions

I have a table with a property that is a foreign key and another property that is a timestamp

Table

| id | fk | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 16-02-2022 |
| 2 | 2 | 01-02-2022 |
| 3 | 2 | 02-02-2021 |
| 4 | 3 | 24-05-2020 |
| 5 | 3 | 11-01-2022 |
| 6 | 3 | 16-09-2021 |
| 7 | 3 | 01-01-2022 |

**I want to select the rows that have more that X ocurrences of the same foreign key and i want to ignore the X most recent(timestamp) elements for each foreign key**

So basically with a X of 2 the select would return

| id | fk | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2 | 02-02-2021 |
| 6 | 3 | 16-09-2021 |
| 4 | 3 | 24-05-2020 |

And with a X of 3 the select would return

| id | fk | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 3 | 24-05-2020 |

**Edit:**

Thanks alot @forpas for the awesome aproach

**Solution**

```
SELECT id, fk, timestamp 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fk) counter,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE counter > ? AND rn > ?;
```

Comment: In MySql 8.0+  you can use window functions. What is your version?

Comment: I use MySql 8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `COUNT()` and `ROW_NUMBER()` window functions:

```
SELECT id, fk, timestamp 
FROM (
  SELECT *,
         COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY fk) counter,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE counter > ? AND rn > ?;
```

Replace `?` with the values that you want.

But, if the same number X is applied for both the number of total rows for each `fk` and the number of rows to be dismissed, the query can be simplified:

```
SELECT id, fk, timestamp 
FROM (
  SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY fk ORDER BY timestamp DESC) rn
  FROM tablename
) t
WHERE rn > ?;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=47933b04b9c79dd176ee47942d7f3842).

Comment: @JonasTrifas check my 2nd query, if it is applicable to your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
id, fk, timestamp
FROM
(
SELECT id, fk, timestamp, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY fk ORDER BY timestamp ASC) AS X,
COUNT(1) OVER(PARTITION BY fk) AS Total
FROM MyTable
) AS S
WHERE A.Total - S.X >= @X
```